# how do I Group by range, or conditionally select from query results

Tags: sql, sql-like, clickhouse

I have a table of user activity and I am trying to get a count of all distinct users for each day for the last 28 days. Like for instance 7/7 would have the distinct count of 7/7 and 6/9 and 7/6 would have distinct count 7/6 through 6/8

I can't just get distinct users per day and add them up, because, throughout the range, the distinct user count would be double counting. It's easy enough to just this number for 1 day, but I need it for everyday we are collecting data

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

uniqStates can be summed

```
create table u (date Date, uid Int64) Engine=Memory;
insert into u select toDate('2021-01-01') + number, arrayJoin( range(number,  number*2+5 ) ) from numbers(31);

select x.1 date, uniqMerge(x.2) uniq_per_date, uniqMerge(arrayJoin(y)) uniq_from_beginning from (select groupArray( (date, s) ) xx, arrayMap( i-> arraySlice(xx.2, 1, i), range(length(xx))) yy from (select date, uniqState(uid) s from u group by date order by date)) array join xx as x, yy as y group by date　;

┌───────date─┬─uniq_per_date─┬─uniq_from_beginning─┐
│ 2021-01-02 │             6 │                   5 │
│ 2021-01-03 │             7 │                   7 │
│ 2021-01-04 │             8 │                   9 │
│ 2021-01-05 │             9 │                  11 │
│ 2021-01-06 │            10 │                  13 │
│ 2021-01-07 │            11 │                  15 │
│ 2021-01-08 │            12 │                  17 │
│ 2021-01-09 │            13 │                  19 │
│ 2021-01-10 │            14 │                  21 │
│ 2021-01-11 │            15 │                  23 │
│ 2021-01-12 │            16 │                  25 │
```